# why Object.getOwnPropertyNames for a DOM returns empty array?

Tags: javascript, dom

In the following simplest html snippet:

```
<button class="clickme" id="clickme">click me</button>
```

i use the following javascript code to query dom and want to inspect which properties and methods on the objects returned by the getElementById:

```
var btn=document.getElementById('clickme');console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(btn));
```

My question is:
1. why above log only dumps out a [] empty string??
2. What is the type of returned value by getElementById?

Thanks~!

Comment: `getElementById` returns reference of the DOM element. Returned element has no direct properties hence empty array is returned..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. why above log only dumps out a [] empty string

All the properties of the object (Element) are inherited from  Node, and its own parent, EventTarget, and implements those of ParentNode, ChildNode, NonDocumentTypeChildNode, and Animatable.

Since it has no direct property of its own, so it returns an empty array.

> 2. What is the type of returned value by getElementById?

It returns an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element).